# Node.js Telegram bot can't kick user from supergroup

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to create a logic system to kick a username from a private supergroup.
But, when function is running I'm returning:

```
Api error: Body: {
  ok: false,
  error_code: 400,
  description: 'Bad Request: wrong user_id specified'
}


(node:11272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<TelegramApiError>
(node:11272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11272) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm calling the function inside a handle with: `$.kickChatMember(groupid , userid);`

Thank you!

Comment: The error says that the user_id is wrong. Did you check if the intended value is going in the request?

Comment: @ArunSelin yes, I'm sure that user_id is right

Comment: It's solved! My code was wrong. when we use an scope, it send automatically the id of chat, so, we just need to send userid: `$.kickChatMember(userid);`

Answer (score 1):

It's solved! My code was wrong. 
When we use an scope, it sends automatically the id of chat, so, we just need to send userid as parametre: `$.kickChatMember(userid);`